# Result Not Display in Json when use sms api

Tags: php, json

```
$url='https://mysmsapi.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey='.AUTHKEY.'&mobiles='.$mob_no.'&message='.urlencode(MESSAGE .$key).'&sender='.SENDER.'&response=json&route='.ROUTE;
        $ch      = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $resp  = curl_exec($ch);
        $json = json_decode($resp);

        if($json->type == 'success')
        {
            mysql_query("insert into mobile_sms_verifier_data(mobile_no,email,name,verification_key) values('$mob_no','$email','$name','$key')");

            $id = mysql_insert_id();

            $responce = '<table align="center" border="1"><tr><td align="center">Enter Verification Code</td></tr><tr><td align="center"><input type="hidden" value="'.$id.' " id="verification_id"><input type="text" id="verification_key" maxlength="5" placeholder="verification code"></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="verify_mobile_no()"><p id="v_msg"></p></td></tr></table>';
        }
        elseif($json->type == 'error')
        {
            $responce = '<p style="text-align: center;color:red;">Please Enter valid mobile no.  <a href="">  Try Again </a></p>';
        } 
        echo $responce;
        die();

}
```

its working fine but when am using my SMS API

```
$url='http://1.1.1.1/sendsms.jsp?user=test&password=test&mobiles='.$mob_no.'&sms='.urlencode(MESSAGE .$key).'&senderid='.SENDER.'&response=json';
```

then JSON not gets success and not display input for verify code.

no idea where is issue...

funtion use for verify no.

```
  function verify_mobile_no()
{ 
    var key = $.trim($('#verification_key').val());
    var verification_id = $('#verification_id').val();
    if(key == "") 
    {
        $('#v_msg').html("<span style='color:red'>Please, Enter Verification Code!!</span>");
    }
    else
    {
        var uniqid=$('#uniqid').val();
        $.ajax({
            method:'post',
            url:'ajax_call.php',
            data:{'verification_key':key,'v_id':verification_id}
        })
        .done(function(msg){
                $('#v_msg').html("");
                $('#result').html('<p style="font-size:30px;">'+msg+'</p>');
                setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 7000);
        });
    }
}
```

result show as

```
<div id="result" style="margin:20px auto; text-align:center;"></div>
```

please help me where is issue ??

note : my sms api dont have auth key and route its with user and pass so i use that as above.

Comment: what happens when you hard code the link and then directly run it in the browser

Comment: maybe the output result of your SMS API is different with the first one ?!

Comment: @DhavalChheda I get SMS in my mobile and data inserted in the database but input not open for insert code for verify

Comment: @pejmankheyri output means its input box for insert code that's not displayed if am using my SMS API why it does not pass success

Comment: @anupdwivedi So your sms sends and data inserts to database ?!

Comment: @pejmankheyri yes only json not execute for input box where i need to insert verify code which i got in SMS

Comment: Please add var_dump($id) after $id = mysql_insert_id() what is the result?

Comment: @pejmankheyri its give Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$responce' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/ajax_call.php on line 40

Comment: oh i use without semicolan i hope thats why its give this if use semicolon then no error in this !@pejmankheyri

Comment: So you are now not getting any errors ?!

Comment: no dear no error.....json not get success @pejmankheyri

Comment: add var_dump($json); before if($json->type == 'success') 
what is the result?

Comment: @pejmankheyri its show NULL

Comment: Are you sure about that data insert into DB?
var_dump($resp); to check if there is any response from curl execution !

Comment: no, this time no data inserted if am using before if($json->type == 'success') but i got sms in my mobile so curl is working @pejmankheyri

Comment: @pejmankheyri when use var_dump($resp); got this NULL string(214) " 219908808 683082219 +919876543210 "